# Найти повторяющиеся значения массива

Tags: массивы, java

Доброй ночи. Ребята, прошу больно не пинать и опять помочь:)

Есть такая задача

> Для проверки остаточных знаний учеников после летних каникул, учитель младших классов решил начинать каждый урок с того, чтобы задавать каждому ученику пример из таблицы умножения, но в классе 15 человек, а примеры среди них не должны повторяться. В помощь учителю напишите программу, которая будет выводить на экран 15 случайных примеров из таблицы умножения (от 2x2 до 9x9, потому что задания по умножению на 1 и на 10 — слишком просты). При этом среди 15 примеров не должно быть повторяющихся (примеры 2x3 и 3x2 и им подобные пары считать повторяющимися).

Просто вывести как 15 разных примеров нету проблем. Через создание массива в 15 строк и 3 столбца.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] massiv = new int[15][3];

    for (int x = 0; x < massiv.length; x++) {

        massiv[x][0] = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
        massiv[x][1] = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
        massiv[x][2] = (massiv[x][0]) * (massiv[x][1]);

    }

    for (int x = 0; x < massiv.length; x++) {

        System.out.println("Пример №" + (x + 1) + ":\t\t" + massiv[x][0] + " * " + massiv[x][1] + " = " + massiv[x][2]);

    }}
}
```

и вообще не имею никаких мыслей как произвести проверку
подскажите, натолкните хоть в какую сторону копать?

Comment: А еще можно добавить вариант с множеством. Только числа в каждой сгенеренной паре надо сразу упорядочивать.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите. Для начала, какие вообще у нас есть примеры? А вот какие:

```
2 x 2    2 x 3    2 x 4    ...    2 x 9
         3 x 3    3 x 4    ...    3 x 9
                  4 x 4    ...    4 x 9
                           ...
                                  9 x 9
```

Их всего 8 + 7 + ... + 1 = (сумма арифметической прогрессии) = (8 + 1) * 8 / 2 = 36. Закодируем их пока просто номерами от 0 до 35. Наша первая подзадача — отобрать из набора чисел выборку из 15 штук. Это делается при помощи выборки с резервуаром (Кнут, Искусство программирования, 3.4.2S):

```
const int N = 36; const int n = 15;
int[] values = new int[n];

Random random = new Random();
int targetIdx = 0, source = 0;
while (targetIdx < n)
{
    int r = random.nextInt(N - source);
    if (r < n - targetIdx)
        values[targetIdx++] = source;
    source++;
}
```

Итак, у нас есть массив случайных неповторяющихся номеров примеров. Осталось по номеру примера выдать сам пример.

Для этого сначала найдём столбец. Пусть номер столбца `k`, тогда `k` — наибольшее целое такое, что

```
(1 + k) * k / 2 <= v
```

то есть

```
k * k + k <= 2 * v
k * k + k + 1/4 <= 2 * v + 1/4
(k + 1/2)^2 <= 2 * v + 1/4
k + 1/2 <= sqrt(2 * v + 1/4)
k = floor(sqrt(2 * v + 1/4) - 1/2)
```

Строка находится теперь легко.

---

PS: Вместо вычисления корня можно применить нанооптимизацию и воспользоваться предвычисленным массивом. Даст выгоду в долю миллисекунды.

Comment: А второй сомножитель всегда будет не меньше первого? Нехорошо...

Comment: @alexlz: Это да, можно ещё одним `random.nextBool` перемешать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать следующий код:

```
int[][] mass = new int[15][3];
for (int x = 0; x < mass.length; x++) {
    label:
    while (true) {
        int a = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
        int b = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
        for (int y = 0; y < mass.length; y++) {
            if ((a == mass[y][0] && b == mass[y][1]) || (b == mass[y][0] && a == mass[y][1])) {
                continue label;
            }
        }
        mass[x][0] = a;
        mass[x][1] = b;
        mass[x][2] = (mass[x][0]) * (mass[x][1]);
        break label;
    }
}
for (int x = 0; x < mass.length; x++) {
    System.out.println("Пример №" + (x + 1) + ": " + mass[x][0] + " * " + mass[x][1] + " = " + mass[x][2]);
}
```

Comment: добавь описание что происходит в твоем коде